# PixieDust App is not possible run in container with Czech locale

Tags: pixiedust

Please i have Jupyter Python notebook with PixieDust 1.1.1 and I try to deploy it as standalone web app in a container according this guide https://medium.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/deploy-your-analytics-as-web-apps-using-pixiedusts-1-1-release-d08067584a14
It works fine with default English locale, but it doesn't work when I try to use Czech locale in the notebook:

- import locale
- loc = locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,‘cs_CZ’)

Any idea how to fix/install additional locales to the container?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the locale is missing from the docker image used to deploy PixieGateway on a Kubernetes container.

To solve it, you'll need to install the cs_CZ locale manually.

Here are the steps:

1. kubectl exec -it [pod_name] /bin/bash   (you can get the pod-name with kubectl get pods)
2. In the pod shell type: dpkg-reconfigure locales
3. Select the locale for cs_CZ (number 88)
4. ctrl+D to get out

Note: You'll need to republish the Notebook PixieApp to force a kernel restart.